# Explode Group_Concat Then Split into 2 Groups if Count is more than 4

Tags: php, mysql

I have used explode() and then count to:

This is part of a SELECT statement:

```
GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN c.twitter IS NOT NULL AND c.twitter <> '' 
THEN CONCAT('!',c.twitter) END SEPARATOR ' ') AS tweetWinners 

$tweeters = $row['tweetWinners'];

$twit = explode(' ' , $tweeters);
$countTwits = count($twit);
```

When I echo $tweeters I will get:

```
!twitter1 !twitter2 !twitter3 and so on
```

The $countTwits tells me how many twitter users there are.  However what I am wanting to do, say for example $countTwits returns the result 7, then I want to store the first 4 in a variable and then the last 3 in another, therefore splitting them up.  So:

```
if $countTwits > 4 record first 4 as $tweets1 and last 3 as $tweets2
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect what you look for is [array_chunk()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php) function:

```
// to split into two more-o-less equal parts
$just_two_chunks = array_chunk($twit, ceil($countTwits / 2));

// to split into arrays of at least 4 items
$chunks_by_four = array_chunk($twit, 4);
```

You can turn any array into a set of variables with `list`:

```
list($tweets1, $tweets2) = $just_two_chunks;
```

... but I honestly doubt using those would be easier than that array.

---

Now onto this new task: inserting this array by 4 items in chunk. One possible way:

```
$twits_by_four = array_chunk($twit, 4);
foreach ($twits_by_four as $chunk)  {
  insertRow($chunk);
}
```

Comment: I will be using `if ($countTwits > 4) { INSERT INTO table (twitUsers) VALUES ($first4users) AND THEN INSERT INTO table (twitUsers) VALUES ($secondSetofUsers)` so this would basically create two new rows in the database.  Not sure how that would work with your solution.

Comment: Erm. Perhaps I'm missing something, but - do you have four separate columns for those users, and that's why you need them to be grouped as such? Why can't you use just a single insert, I mean?

Comment: No they get all inserted into one column.  It basically forms a tweet which includes usernames.  However, the tweet goes past 140 characters when more than 4 usernames are present so the reason for more than 4 usernames would be to insert a new line in to the database for the other 3.  Then I have some code further down that tweets new lines that have been entered into the database.

Comment: @andy Ok, then just 1) use `array_chunk($twit, 4)` to get array of N elements of 4 names each (the last item may have fewer than 4); 2) insert all these chunks in a loop that iterates over this array.

Comment: Is there anyway you could illustrate that in your example, that would be great :-) Thank you, Andy

Comment: Added to the answer. But actually I don't understand why you cannot do multi-insert here, if MySQL is in use. BTW, which extension is employed - mysqli or PDO?

Comment: mysqli is employed.  I'm not sure how I would do a multi insert when the number of tweeters is variable, it may be 5 or it maybe 15.  What I wanted as mentioned before is `if > 4 then add the first 4 to the first tweet and the rest to the 2nd. if > 8 then add 4 to first tweet, second 4 to second tweet and rest to 3rd tweet`